# Comparing number always return false

Tags: javascript

I generate a random number with an interval and then I check if the number chooses by the user is the same, but it always returns false

```js
const checkButton = document.getElementById("checkButton");
var rndNumber = RandomNumberGenerator();
checkButton.onclick = CheckNumber;
console.log("rndNumber", rndNumber);

function CheckNumber(rndNumber) {
  var numberChoosed = document.getElementById("numberChoosed").value;
  console.log("rndNumber", rndNumber)
  console.log("numberChoosed", numberChoosed);
  if (numberChoosed == rndNumber) {
    console.log("true");
  } else {
    console.log("False");
  }

}

function RandomNumberGenerator() {
  var min = document.getElementById("bottomNumber").value;
  var max = document.getElementById("topNumber").value;
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="checkButton">Click</button>

<input id="numberChoosed" />
<input id="bottomNumber" value="1"/>
<input id="topNumber" value="110"/>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to add a [*minimal*, *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I made you a snippet. What are the steps and what is the expected output? Please change the snippet to reflect your actual setup

Comment: `function CheckNumber(rndNumber) {` should be `function CheckNumber(event) {` so that you are not shadowing the global `rndNumber` variable which you want to access

Comment: I think that you have to check argument passed to `CheckNumber` function. I think that you can remove arguement `rndNumber` in order to avoid variable name clash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `rndNumber` from `function CheckNumber(rndNumber) {` because that is actually the click event on the checkButton

Also a good idea to cast to number since `.value` is a string.

The `==` will cast for you but it is no longer up to you then

```js
const checkButton = document.getElementById("checkButton");
var rndNumber = RandomNumberGenerator();
checkButton.onclick = CheckNumber;
console.log("rndNumber", rndNumber);

function CheckNumber() {
  var numberChoosed = document.getElementById("numberChoosed").value;
  console.log("rndNumber", rndNumber)
  console.log("numberChoosed", numberChoosed);
  console.log(+numberChoosed === +rndNumber); // cast to number

}

function RandomNumberGenerator() {
  var min = document.getElementById("bottomNumber").value;
  var max = document.getElementById("topNumber").value;
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="checkButton">Click</button>

<input id="numberChoosed" />
<input id="bottomNumber" value="1"/>
<input id="topNumber" value="110"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong rndNumber value. Parameter passed in CheckNumber method is not the rndnumber. Try creating the rnd number inside the CheckNumber method :

```js
const checkButton = document.getElementById("checkButton");

checkButton.onclick = CheckNumber;

function CheckNumber() {
  var numberChoosed = document.getElementById("numberChoosed").value;
  var rndNumber = RandomNumberGenerator();
  console.log("rndNumber", rndNumber);

  console.log("rndNumber", rndNumber)
  console.log("numberChoosed", numberChoosed);
  if (Number(numberChoosed) == Number(rndNumber)) {
    console.log("true");
  } else {
    console.log("False");
  }

}

function RandomNumberGenerator() {
  var min = document.getElementById("bottomNumber").value;
  var max = document.getElementById("topNumber").value;
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="checkButton">Click</button>

<input id="numberChoosed" />
<input id="bottomNumber" value="1"/>
<input id="topNumber" value="110"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

U have done a small mistake ,
You have saved random value on variable called        **rndNumber**         , and you are passing same variable in button click function argument .
scope of variable is getting affected ,
**rndNumber** in button click function returns event object

pls remove **`rndNumber`** from  **`function CheckNumber(rndNumber) {`**

attaching jsfiddle also

https://jsfiddle.net/v9d1fqex/